# How to handle different languages with Google Actions and DiaglogflowApp with Firebase functions

Tags: actions-on-google

I have configured multiple languages in my Dialogflow agent. I cannot figure out how to detect the language of the request in my firebase function in order to answer with the right language. Is there a standard approach to handle this? I don't see any function to detect the language in https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs

I would expect to be able to do something like this:

```
const app = new DialogflowApp({request: request, response: response});
if (app.getLang == 'en') { 
    \\ Do something in english 
}
else if (app.getLang == 'es') { 
    \\ Do something in spanish 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a public sample on the AoG GitHub for [Number Genie](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-number-genie-nodejs), which is in both French and English.

In this sample they define [JSON objects](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-number-genie-nodejs/tree/master/functions/locales) for English and French locales:

```
{
"images": {
    "cold": {
        "url": "COLD.gif",
        "altText": "cold genie",
        "cardText": [
            "Freezing like an ice cave in Antarctica?",
            "I can't feel my face anymore",
            "Hurry, before I turn into an icicle"
        ]
    },
    ...

{
"images": {
    "cold": {
        "url": "COLD.gif",
        "altText": "Génie froid",
        "cardText": [
            "Je me gèle comme un glaçon en Antartique",
            "Je ne sens plus mon visage",
            "Dépêchez-vous avant que je ne me transforme en glaçon"
        ]
    },
    ...
```

Then there is a central [strings.js](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-number-genie-nodejs/blob/master/functions/strings.js) file which will pull the correct string for that locale.

```
const i18n = require("i18n");

i18n.configure({
   "directory": __dirname + "/locales",
   "objectNotation": true,
   "fallbacks": {
     "fr-FR": "fr",
     "fr-CA": "fr"
   }
});

const prompts = () => ({
"welcome": {
  "visual": {
    "elements": [
      [i18n.__("variants.greeting"), i18n.__("variants.invocation")],
      i18n.__("variants.invocationGuess"),
      i18n.__("images.intro")
    ],
    "suggestions": onlyNumberSuggestions
  }
},
...
```

Which is then used to [map to each intent](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-number-genie-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js):

```
  [Actions.GENERATE_ANSWER] () {
    this.data.answer = strings.getRandomNumber(strings.numbers.min,
```

strings.numbers.max);
        this.data.guessCount = 0;
        this.data.fallbackCount = 0;
        this.data.steamSoundCount = 0;
        this.ask(strings.prompts.welcome, strings.numbers.min, strings.numbers.max);
      }

The locale is set by getting that from the `app.getUserLocale()` method:

```
/**
 * Get the Dialogflow intent and handle it using the appropriate method
 */
run () {
  strings.setLocale(this.app.getUserLocale());
  /** @type {*} */
  const map = this;
  const action = this.app.getIntent();
  console.log(action);
  if (!action) {
    return this.app.ask(`I didn't hear a number. What's your guess?`);
  }
  map[action]();
}
```

There's definitely a lot here, and you don't need to do this exactly the same way. `app.getUserLocale()` should return the current locale, which you can then use in any way that you want to return the response.

Comment: but DialogflowApp doesn't have a `getUserLocale` method. I cannot do `app.getUserLocale()`

Comment: It's part of the super `AssistantApp` class: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/AssistantApp#getUserLocale